# OGR writing MapInfo Tabfiles with column Indexes

Tags: ogr, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I'm using ogr2ogr to convert MSSQL to MapInfo File and would like to add indexes to some of my MapInfo columns, is this possible?

This is what I have so far

```
set ogr2ogr="C:\Program Files\GDAL\ogr2ogr.exe"
set sqlcon="MSSQL:server=SQL;database=Spatial;User id=user;Password=password;MARS_Connection=yes;"

%ogr2ogr% -f "MapInfo File" test.tab %sqlcon% -sql "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tableName]"
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of MapInfo driver of GDAL http://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html mentions only spatial index so I believe that driver can't create indexes for attributes. However, the mitab driver does seem to have support for utilising the .IND index if such exists https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/013f4087c9468aff66e60a82a8ca326fe9609730